# Swift filter items on realm

Tags: swift, realm

```
 if (carData != "" && carData2 != "" && carData3 != "") {
        selectedCar = selectedCar?.filter("(carCountry == %@ && carColor == %@ && carBrand == %@) OR (carCountry == %@ && carBrand == %@ && carColor == %@) OR (carColor == %@ && carCountry == %@ && carBrand == %@)", carData, carData2, carData3, carData, carData3, carData2, carData2, carData, carData3)
 }
```

I want to filter items on realm database based on three properties which are "carData","carData2","carData3". These properties come from what user typed on each three textfield. I want to make it possible for users to filter items by whichever textfield they use. I can filter

```
(carCountry == %@ && carColor == %@ && carBrand == %@)
```

this part, but other two part don't work at all.

Comment: what is carData? is it string? or what is selectedCar? is it array?

Comment: for a start - if you're trying to make it so that the user can enter the data in whichever field they choose - which seems odd - you will need 6 combinations to cover all of the options, not the three that you have

Comment: PPL: It is array. Result<Cars>. I use realm.

Comment: Russel: I know that I have to write 6 combinations. but I thought it is unnecessary to write for now. anyway, you got what I want to do perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried `||` rather than `OR`? FYI, all 3 conditions you wrote are same, you moved the parameter in condition-2 but also moved the input carData2 and carData3 as well.

Comment: Ankit Jayaswal: I tried your advice, and my code perfectly worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have issue in search parameter.

If parameter type String then use `contains`

Example :-

```
let someDogs = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("name contains 'Fido'")
```

If parameter type Int then use `==`

Example :-

```
let myPuppy = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age == 1")
```

Please try as per your parameter type.

Comment: I tried CONTAINS at first. but also it didn't work. I think    (carCountry == %@ && carColor == %@ && carBrand == %@)  this part is initiated in priority to at any conditions. so the part in the back won't be referred.

Comment: I wanted to show the filtered result on tableView. When I enter text fits to the first part in the filter, it works perfectly. However, when I try to use the other 2 part in the back, I got blank tableView. so maybe any values are set on selectedCar property.